# How do I elevate privileges in the middle of pipeline?

Tags: shell, shell-script, io-redirection, su

My guess was as follows:

```
echo "Generating some text" | su - -c cat >/output/file
```

But `su` says:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

What would you do?

Comment: If you found a solution yourself, please add it as answer below.

Comment: @Braiam The solution doesn't deserve to be an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo` supports this.

```
$ echo hello world | sudo cat  
SUDO password: 
hello world
```

The difference being that `sudo` asks for your user password, not the `root` (target user) password. However if you so desire, you can change this behavior with the `targetpw` (or `runaspw` or `rootpw`) directive in `sudoers.conf`.

---

However reading what you're trying to do, while this solves the permission escalation problem, it won't do what you expect. Meaning `/output/file` will not be created as the root user, it will be created/modified as your user.

The reason for this is that shell output redirection is done before invoking any commands. So the shell opens `/output/file` and then passes that opened file to `su` / `sudo` (and consequently, `cat`).

However you can use `tee` to do this instead, as the `tee` utility will open the file itself.

```
echo "hello world" | sudo tee /output/file >/dev/null
```

Basically `tee` copies the output into `/output/file` and STDOUT, however STDOUT is redirected into `/dev/null`.

You could also do:

```
echo "hello world" | sudo sh -c 'cat > /output/file'
```

...which is less cryptic.

Comment: You may also "cache" elevated privileges by invoking `sudo -v`. It'll ask for your password if you haven't used sudo in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know - you're not limited to a single command per `|pipe`:

```
this happens | then this | { then ; all of ; this too ; } | before this
```

All of those processes are invoked at the same time - but they all wait on the `|pipe` before them before actually doing anything - so long as they read the `|pipe` at all, that is. So, if you need to evaluate a variable midstream, or to setup a redirection, you can. Just take your time.

```
echo "it takes time" |
{ exec 4>|file ; cat >&4 ; } |
( sleep 1 && cat <file )

it takes time
```

Here is another way:

```
echo "more of the same" |
( IFS= ; su -mc 'echo '"$(printf "'%s' " "`cat`")"' >|file' </dev/tty ) |
echo end of pipe
```

If you don't `( subshell )` the command `$(cat)` will get `</dev/tty` as well.

But if you're using a here-doc, you don't need two `cat`s:

```
rm ./file
su -c 'cat <&3 >|./file; echo "middle here"' 3<<HERE >&2 | {\
    until [ -s ./file ] ; do sleep 1 ; done ;\
    sed 's/beginning/end/' ./file ; }
$(echo "this is the beginning" | sed 'a\of the pipeline' | tee /dev/stderr)
HERE
```

OUTPUT:

```
this is the beginning
of the pipeline
Password:
middle here
this is the end
of the pipeline
```

Most of the above is just to demo this. All you really need is:

```
su -c 'cat <&3 >./file' 3<<HERE | { wait as needed ; more stuff to do ; }
$(echo "something" | and other things)
HERE
```

Comment: I know that. That has little or nothing to do with the question, or so I think. But somehow it led me to an answer :) See my updated question.

Comment: @x-yuri You can still put a here-document in the middle of a pipeline. echo something | { su 'do some stuff >/record.here' ; } <<HERE | echo end of pipe\n$(cat)\nHERE\n

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think of using cat inside of here document. Anyway, you don't need grouping there.

Comment: @x-yuri  - that depends on what you want to do with it. You can use either or both. I was only trying to demonstrate you had options. Patrick's answer is the correct one here, this is just another, more convoluted way. That here-doc does group, though - it groups cat in a subshell.

Comment: By grouping I meant [curly braces](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping).